# Google places INVALID_REQUEST during query

Tags: url, request

I create the following URL to get places in a certain area:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=38.78989,-77.63975&radius=32186&sensor=true&types=restaurant&rankby=distance&key=

And I get the following reply:
    
      INVALID_REQUEST

For the life of me, I dont see what could be wrong in the URL.
In the Google console for Reports, the graph is incrementing for each request, so I know the key is hooked up properly.

Answer (score 0):

In turns out the radius is not required and should not be used.  Google only returns at most 30 responses.